# Proxy Selenium Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, случайные-числа, proxy

У меня есть список с прокси, и мне надо, ip менялся каждый раз, когда перехожу на сайт 2ip.ru; чтобы использованные прокси из списка proxy уже не использовались, и когда все прокси будут использованы, остановить код.
То есть, каждый цикл менять ip, но использовать только новые ip.
Вот мой код, он не работает

```
proxy = ["193.200.12.126:8052","193.151.190.14:8052","193.233.251.231:8052"]
while True:
    PROXY = proxy[random.randint(0,2)]
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    print(PROXY)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://2ip.ru')
```

Тут повторяются прокси. Надо, чтобы не повторялось, и, желательно, по порядку использовались, а если уже все прокси были использованы, остановить скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Где, а главное зачем  вы угнали рандомизатор?

```
proxys = ["193.200.12.126:8052","193.151.190.14:8052","193.233.251.231:8052"]
for proxy in proxys:
    options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy})
    print(proxy)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://2ip.ru')
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Вот код для Selenium 4.x, чтобы включить прокси надо задать опции браузера данные параметры с низу (ssl - это https), а остальное понятно из названий, что бы узнать эти параметры я заходил в конфиг браузера и в ручную проверял что бы подобрать.

Так же я знаю как убрать проверку на бота в драйвере, для этого нужно закомпилить своего водителя на раст

```
def main():
    url = "https://2ip.ru/"

    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx")
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 8000)
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8000)

    serviceDriver = Service(
    executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\driver\geckodriver.exe")

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=serviceDriver)
    driver.get("https://2ip.ru")
```